# Can't print a model value with underscore in html property (in a _.each)

Tags: underscore.js

I observed an issue with underscore trying to access a data in a HTML property:

For a model with an `id` and a `name` properties

```
<% _.each(collection, function(model){ %>
  <div data-id="<% model.id %>" class="item active"><%= model.name %></div>
<% }); %>
```

Here, i get `<div data-id="" class="item active c">Test</div>`, if i do:

```
<% _.each(collection, function(model){ %>
  <div data-id="<% model.id %>" class="item active"><%= model.name %></div>
<% }); %>
```

i get `<div data-id="" class="item active c">0</div>`

So i can't print into the "data-id" property, it seems to be because i am in a `each` because i can do this in another part of my code.

Do you know a way to avoid that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just one more `=` sign away!

```
<% _.each(collection, function(model){ %>
  <div data-id="<%= model.id %>" class="item active"><%= model.name %></div>
<% }); %>
```